# WebKit display: table; bug?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am having a "WebKit only issue" which is rather strange to me. But I have elements (in this case an a tag) that has `display: table;` applied too it. And it has a child div that has `display: none;` that when hovered shows `display: table-cell;`. The reason for this is to allow the div to be vertically aligned in the `a` tag.

http://jsbin.com/oqIlAsa/1/

Yet when I hover over it, it doesn't align it middle. And when I remove hover over, it disappears and takes the parent with it. This only happens with WebKit. IE, FireFox, etc all work as intended. This is also a new issue, it worked fine when I tested it 11 (ish) months ago.

Any ideas? Is this a WebKit bug or bad coding that the other browsers allow?

Comment: It does look like a bug.  from [section 9.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes): "The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and 'table'."

Comment: It appears to be a "Blink" bug not a "WebKit" bug, it works fine on the latest Safari. So I submitted it to the blink project as a bug. Incase anyone is interested https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286432&thanks=286432&ts=1378496474